# Error with the sum function in sql with Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to sum the total price from invoices (named Total_TTC in table FACT) depending on the code of the taker ( named N_PRENEUR in the two concerned tables) and store the result in the DEBIT_P column of the table table_preneur.
Doing so i get a syntax error (missing operator) In access and can't seem to understand why. I tried other posts and the usggestions returned me the same error.

```
    UPDATE P 
SET DEBIT_P = t.somePrice
FROM table_preneur AS P INNER JOIN
 (
  SELECT
   N_PRENEUR,
    SUM(Total_TTC) somePrice
  FROM
     FACT
  GROUP BY N_PRENEUR
  ) t
ON t.N_PRENEUR = p.N_PRENEUR
```

thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    with cte as
    (select t.somePrice
    from table_preneur as P
    inner join (select SUM(Total_TTC) as somePrice
      from FACT
      group by N_PRENEUR) t  
    on t.N_PRENEUR = p.N_PRENEUR)

    update P 
    set DEBIT_P = cte.somePrice
    -- DO YOU NEED A WHERE CLAUSE?

    --or maybe

    update table_preneur
set DEBIT_P = (select t.somePrice
from table_preneur as P
inner join (select SUM(Total_TTC) as somePrice
  from FACT
  group by N_PRENEUR) t  
on t.N_PRENEUR = p.N_PRENEUR)
```

Comment: It Returned an error expected STATEMENT 'SELECT' 'DELETE' 'UPDATE' .... I first tought it was because of case sensitivity but even after using upper case still didn't work. Maybe the WITH statement is not recognized in access. But thanks though

Comment: I don't think i need a where clause, this sum has to appear for all the clients that have an invoice. I tried the second version of your code and there is progress. No more syntax error; but when compiling, they tell me the MS ACCESS database engine cannot find the input table or querry P !!!! Oh my, Microsoft is annoying no matter the product we are dealing with

Comment: @user2497624 Try that, it didnt know what P was, I was saying update P, I have changed it now to table_preneur, there may be some other incorrectly named tables and fields, check everything exists and is named properly before you try running it

Comment: I'm sorry if i take long to reply, but my connexion is slowww. Oddly enough it worked now that you replace the P by the table it refferenced (although i still wonder wh it didn't work at first). So now that it compiled i got the result in the DEBIT_P column of table preneur. But the sum wasn't done for all the preneurs i have and the result shown is 0 for all of them. I checked my fact table and it does contain invoices for all preneurs (except 1) and the Total_TTC column holds values different from 0 so the sum should not be 0
Sorry if such an apparently easy problem is taking so much time

Comment: Sorry, after further analysis, the 0 i was talking about was the default value of the column (didn't apply it to the first entries, thus my confusion). When i run the querry it asks me to enter t.N_PRENEUR, which implies that it doesn't recognize the refference t we used

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `as` keyword before your column alias `somePrice`:

```
UPDATE P 
SET DEBIT_P = t.somePrice
FROM table_preneur AS P INNER JOIN
 (
  SELECT
   N_PRENEUR,
    SUM(Total_TTC) as somePrice
  FROM
     FACT
  GROUP BY N_PRENEUR
  ) t
ON t.N_PRENEUR = p.N_PRENEUR
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify the above, in MS Access SQL, you need to use AS when declaring a table alias - this is missing from your SQL (SUM(Total_TTC) AS somePrice)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, i tried adding the add as suggested by you and @Mansfield , but i still got the same error. It seems like i might have more errors in the code. I also tried using the AS with "t" i use at the end of the parenthesis with the sum but no success there either.